# Running Total by Year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table broken out into a series of numbers by year, and need to build a running total column but restart during the next year.

The desired outcome is below

```
Amount | Year | Running Total
-----------------------------
  1      2000         1
  5      2000         6
 10      2000        16
  5      2001         5
 10      2001        15
  3      2001        18
```

I can do an ORDER BY to get a standard running total, but can't figure out how to base it just on the year such that it does the running total for each unique year.

Comment: Why would this have gotten a negative vote????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.  One you have this, it is a simple cumulative sum:

```
select amount, year, sum(amount) over (partition by year order by <ordering column>)
from t;
```

Without a column that specifies ordering, "cumulative sum" does not make sense on a table in SQL.

Comment: So would it work like this then, I assume - sum(Calc) over (partition by year(DateTime) order by DateTime) CalcCume1,

Comment: @Danimov82 . . . Yes, that would be correct if you have a `datetime` column.